# Spring Annotation-based Project Templates

Tags: spring-tool-suite

I am new to Spring. I am learning it from different sources. Spring Recipes, Spring In Action and Spring documentation. According to Spring 3.+, XML configuration can be ignored at all. This is good for me as a beginner.

Problem:
I am using Spring Tool Suite, is there a Spring Web project template that starts with annotations only? All the  project templates I have found use XML configuration. I don't even know where to put my `DispatcherServlet`. I don't know where to put my controllers.

Answer (score 1):

I also had the same problem when Starting out with Spring to find only annotation based templates. Then I found [this](https://github.com/springframeworkguru/spring-core-spring-mvc)  from John Thompson. This project is completely annotation based and the only xml file involved is pom.xml

Comment: Thanks brother, I am taking a look. Is there a way we can let them hear about this? Like ask Spring Community to consider adding this?

Comment: Note that this adds no value over what can be trivially generated on http://start.spring.io/

Comment: @kryger I believe you are talking about the project on the master branch. If you look at the various branches on the repo you will see how to use different annotations and how to wire things up in Spring.

Answer (score 1):

The official recommendation is to base  all new projects on Spring Boot which is XML-less out of the box.

STS offers a nice integration with the [Spring Initializr service](http://start.spring.io/): just go to "New -> Spring Starter Project", fill in a few fields like project name etc. and tick the boxes next to modules you're interested in.

[image: STS new project menu]

Comment: you can also use the "Import Spring Getting Started Content", it lets you choose from the Spring Guides (as mentioned in the other answer) and imports those projects directly into your workspace.

Comment: The initializer is a great tool, but it really only helps putting together a coherent pom or build.gradle. THe app it generates is pretty much empty and so does not show much about how to wire beans together with Java annotations. The gs-guides are a better starting point for that.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to run through Spring Guides - they are up to date and use annotation based configuration.
[This is](https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/) guide how to make a restfull web service using spring-boot. It has description how to made project with maven, gradle or STS.

Comment: Yes, and there's also a guide on how to import these guides into STS https://spring.io/guides/gs/sts/